# For a graph with n vertices, are there any polynomial time algorithms to find a k-vertex independent set?

Tags: graph-theory

For a graph with n vertices, how can I find a k-vertex independent set?  (Actually, it doesn't have to be a polynomial-time algorithm, as long as it runs in reasonable time for n = 200, k = 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a NP hard problem if k isn't fixed. If k is fixed, it is trivially polynomial. Also, you're better off asking on one of the other overflow sites for pure algorithmic questions.

As for practical algorithms, what have you tried already? It's possible that even something as simple as greedy search will work with a small problem size.

Comment: Thanks, and what are these trivial polynomial algorithms you speak of?  Haven't tried anything yet, just scoping stuff out to see what I can try.

Comment: @Lol If k is fixed, then even naive brute force is polynomial time since you have to try at most O(n^k) tries. Hence the term trivially.